# How does the command `message.author.bot` work?

Tags: discord.js

`message.author.bot` seems like syntax that is discord.js exclusive, but when used it seems to have no need for the variable storing the imported discord.js. how does this work?

Comment: Without context it's hard to tell what you're asking, but I'm assuming `message` is a message object, and `message.author` is a property that stores the user who sent the message, and `author.bot` is a property that tells you whether or not the user is a bot account.

Answer (score 1):

[`Message.author`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author) is an instance of [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) which has a property called [`bot`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=bot).

*Why is this useful*? you might ask. The [`messageCreate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageCreate) ([`message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-message) on <=v12) event is emitted whenever a new message is created in a [`Channel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel) that the bot can see (this includes [`Direct Messages`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/DMChannel)).

Doesn't matter if a bot account or a user account created the message, the event is emitted.

The [`Message.author`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author)[`.bot`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=bot) property is used to separate bot accounts from normal user accounts so that bots can't execute other bots' commands and preventing infinite loops.

Comment: So can I use `message.author.bot` without having to import Discord.js?

Comment: Yes, if you import the Client, log in using a valid token and listen to the `messageCreate` event.